# How to make a proxy in Sinatra?

Tags: html, ruby, proxy, sinatra

I want to make a simple Sinatra app that when I navigate to "/proxy/:someurl" I will see the exact contents of navigating directly to :someurl, AKA a simple web proxy, sort of like a full-page iframe.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'open-uri'

get '/proxy' do
  url = params[:url]
  raise "GTFO" if (url[0] == '/' || url[0] == '.')
  open(url) do |content|
    content.read.to_s.gsub(/(href|src)=("|')\//, '\1=\2' + url + '/')
  end
end
```

This script gets a page's content, thanks to *[OpenURI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html)*, fixes scripts, stylesheets and images links, then displays the result.

I used a `/proxy?url=http://url.com/` route instead of a `/proxy/url` one. Sinatra doesn't like the slashes and special chars that are usually in URLs.

Comment: That works, but the scrips and stylesheets didn't work.   Have you tried that code?

Comment: Actually it works sometimes (like with yahoo.com) but not others (like with habosa.com), any idea why that is?

By the way there are WAY more that it does work with than those that it does not.

Comment: Using `open-uri` causes this implementation to not only proxy HTTP content, but also local files: `GET /proxy?url=/etc/passwd`. Have fun!

Comment: Yes I tried it, I just wrote it. It doesn't work with habosa because the regular expression that replaces assets links with site.com/asset_link isn't perfect, it looks for a `/` that doesn't exist, because your assets are relative. I guess it would be better to use a DOM parsing URL instead of regular expressions.

Comment: I can probably use some more code to clean up the rest, thank you!

Comment: Thanks @willglynn. I updated my code, what do you think about it?

Comment: Your revised code doesn't stop `GET /proxy?url=../../../etc/passwd` or any of the other variants of the [directory traversal attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack). `open-uri` is simply the wrong tool here -- but as I outlined in my answer, there are lots of other reasons why this is a bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest thing would be to use e.g. RestClient and say:

```
get '/proxy/:url' do |url|
  RestClient.get(url)
end
```

That'd proxy the content of any successful fetch. Do a little more work, and you're piping through content-types and cache-control headers. A little more, and you can pass through error codes. Then POSTs. Then...

That said, I'm not going to help you further because making your web server proxy arbitrary content is a terrible idea. It undermines the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which is the basis of web security. It's slow (tying up your web server waiting for another web server) and/or nontrivial (if you go with `sinatra-async` + `em-http-request`). It makes your web server an anonymizer which totally invites abuse. Just... don't.

- Proxying arbitrary URLs: **bad**.
- Proxying some content from specific URLs you trust: possibly OK, but still probably not the best solution.